# Xcode: Need to lock game to portrait only

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6, portrait

I just released a game to the app store and realized I completely forgot to lock it to portrait only.  I need to submit an updated version that does just that.  At this point, is it enough to just go to general > deployment info and uncheck everything but Portrait and then submit this as a new build?  Or do I also need to do something to the code?  Please note that it's a swift app.

Answer (score 7):

## Simple.

### Here's how you do it.

> This works for both objective c and swift.

#### 1. Open your project and go do your build settings.

[image]

#### Scroll down to the tab that says `Deployment Info`.

[image]

#### 3. From there you can see a section called `Device Orientation`, This is where you need to be. Select an orientation like so.

[image]

#### 4 Build the project and you are done!

[image]

Comment: I fthis helped you be sure to mark this as the answer

Comment: This may not be the right answer as there may be a separate set of keys for iPads. This will only lock iPhones if so, and then you need to modify the plist.

Answer (score 6):

Go to your info.plist file, Supported interface orientations, delete the keys you don't need.

Answer (score 5):

There are two different plist keys for iOS in `info.plist` for orientation,

- Supported Device Orientations
- Supported Device Orientations (iPad)

Both of these must have the appropriate key value pairs in the plist.

Comment: This should be the right answer as sometimes using the graphic approach in the **Deployment Info** section will not override the iPad settings.

Comment: Yes, I've missed the iPad specific one. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

The basic answer is: yes, that should be sufficient.

However:

- Some elements of your application might not adapt well. I know I had problems with the UIImagePickerController for a landscape-only app. So watch out for functionality that you yourself haven't written and how that interacts with the restriction.
- If you have code related to orientation (pushing a certain mode etc) it's probably worth testing.
- You should make the change and test it before submitting. I think there may be ways of holding the release with Apple until you've had the portrait only one approved.