# Xcode: specify orientations for both iPhones and iPads under Deployment Info?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, orientation

[Answers like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29037747/xcode-need-to-lock-game-to-portrait-only) suggest it's possible to lock app orientation by checking boxes under the **Deployment Info** section of the **General** tab in Xcode.

However, doing so only worked for iPhones -- not iPads.

Specifically, we locked the app to only **Portrait** using the **Deployment Info** section but discovered people could still open the app in landscape on iPads.

Then we discovered another set of orientation keys in the app's plist file, which controls the app's orientation on iPads! Meaning the **Deployment Info** solution is misleading because it only works for iPhones.

So is it possible to graphically lock orientation for **both** iPhones and iPads from elsewhere in Xcode (similar to using the **Deployment Info** section), or is the only option to manually modify the plist file?

Screenshot of the Deployment Info section on Xcode 8.3:

[image]

Comment: You also have to check the "Requires full screen" option if you want to prevent your app from rotating on iPad

Comment: @Dan **Requires full screen** is checked. The iPad begins landscape, and the app must only open in portrait -- even when the device is landscape.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under the Deployment Info section there is an iPhone button and an iPad button. Click on iPad and you get a whole new set of options for Main Interface, Device Orientation, and Status Bar Style.

Of course this assumes the app is a Universal app and not an iPhone-only app.

Comment: Where do you see the iPhone/iPad button? Yes, the app is Universal. Thanks!

Comment: Uploaded a screenshot of the Deployment Info section. Xcode 8.3.

Comment: That's odd. In my copy of Xcode 8.3 for my own project, there are two buttons below Devices above Main Interface.

Comment: You can select iphone,ipad or universal from the Devices dropdown list. see  https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdYD5.png.

Comment: @ron27 it is already a universal app as illustrated by the screenshot in the question

Comment: @Crashalot I have the same problem where I can see the iPhone/iPad button in a duplicated target, but not in the original one. I had to open the plist file as source file. Then I searched "UISupportedInterfaceOrientations" and found two entries. After editing the file, the app worked as expected, though I still cannot see the iphone/iPad button in the interface builder. Hope this helps.